# Coq: Is there a way to define "map" for Ensemble

Tags: coq

Is there a way to apply a function to a set in Coq using Ensemble?

That is, to define a function that takes a function `f : A -> A` and a set `S : Ensemble A` and returns an `Ensemble A` such that for `a , In A S a` (i.e. `a` is an element of `S`), the output set "contains" `f a`.

If it is not (which I fear is the case), is there a different way to do this without having to resort to finite sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `Im` and it's defined in [the `Image` module](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.18.0/stdlib/Coq.Sets.Image.html#Im).

```
Require Import Ensembles Image.
About Im.
(* Im (X:Ensemble U) (f:U -> V) : Ensemble V *)
```